# Summing lines in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pyplot figure with a few lines on it. I would like to be able to draw an extra line, which would be a sum of all others' values. The lines are not plotted against the same x values (they are visually shorter in the plot - see the image). The resulting line would be somewhat above all others. [image]
One idea I have for it requires obtaining a line's y value in a specific x point. Is there such a function? Or does pyplot/matplotlib support summing lines' values?

Comment: You will have to to the interpolation and summing your self and then just plot an extra line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future generations: *numpy.interp()* was my solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Superposition it the short answer to your question: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) for more.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.arange(100) #range of x axis
y1 = np.random.rand(100,1) #some random numbers
y2 = np.random.rand(100,1)

#this will only plot y1 value
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.show()

#this will plot summation of two elements
plt.plot(x,y1+y2)
plt.show()
```

I took a second look at your question, what I saw is your y values have different length so adding them would not be the case as shown in example above. What you can do is create equal sized 4 lists, where non existing values in that list is zero, then you can apply super position to this (simply add all of them and then plot)

Comment: Actually, they are all 500 points long, the shorter ones simply have a more 'dense' x